# how to call jquery plugin function from other plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two plugins tabs.js and slideshow.js I need call function timeOut() in tabs.js but I can't accses it becouse it is in slideshow.js file http://rnt999.arvixevps.com/~rnt999/test/slider/main.html this is full code. Please javascaript guru help me!:)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't call it directly without modification. How about simply copying it?

It's just a 7 liner.

```
    var timer;
    function timeOut(interval) 
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
        timer = setTimeout(showNextImage, interval);
    }
```

Comment: anyway I need to call showNextImage() from slideshow.js so this is not solution, but anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: In that case, you should rephrase your question to state what you *actually* want.

Comment: I need call timeOut function from tabs.js plugin.